# Connection String from Excel 2010 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a connection string in an Excel 2010 file that used to pull data from a SQL Server DB.

How do I go about actually creating this connection string?
We switched over to a totally new server and the SQL Server DB name has changed. Is there a way to produce this somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data > Connections >

select the connection it is about, and amend the properties to match the new server parameters

Comment: Thanks K_B. But how do I actually get the Catalog, Data Source info though? Where can I find this at?

Comment: What do you mean by Catalog? Are you using this dialog box? http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Connection-Properties.png